# How to Bind datasource from a static method? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to bind a dataSource from a static method. but i cant see my repeater on my static method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static int setPages(string num)
{
   int result = MarketplaceDataBridge.SetPageNumber(num); 
   repeater1.datasource(result);
   repeater1.databind();     
   return result;
}
```

is it possible to do this?, or what are the ways that i could do to achieve this thanks.

-ive been searching this whole time from calling static to nonstatic and passing ajax values to wherever up to creating webservices haha- sorry for being such a newb-

--Update ive been able to call it this way

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    [WebMethod]
    public static int setPages(string num)
    {
       _Default page = new _Default();
       int result = MarketplaceDataBridge.SetPageNumber(num); 
       page.binder(result);    
       return result;
    }

private void binder(List<MobileApplication> map)
        {
            List<MobileApplication> maps = new List<MobileApplication>();

            maps = map;
            if (maps != null)
            {
                Apps.DataSource = maps;
                Apps.DataBind();
            }

        }
}
```

but im getting errors unhandledNullException but whenever i pass maps it has values in it

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your binder method static also

Comment: then i wont be able to call Apps which is a repeater in my page-